# When will the sitecore azure search provider be released?

Tags: content-search, azure-search

I saw there was a Roadmap from earlier this year saying Azure Search Provider would be included in 8.2 update 1 to be released this year. 
Along with Azure session redis cache.

Has anyone got any updates on the progress of the offical Azure Search provider?

The open source implementation currently have too many issues.